# arrow crossings of curves in xy-pic

Tags: xy-pic

I want a diagram like

[image]

What I can do is

```
\[ 
\xy 
(-10,0)*+{ml}="ml";
(10,0)*+{mr}="mr";
(-5,13)*+{t}="t";
(10,-10)*+{b}="b";
{\ar@{-}@`{(10,0),(0,10),(-10,0)}|(0.11){\hole}|(0.501)\hole|(0.96){\dir{>}} "ml";"mr"};
{\ar@{-}|(0.5){\hole}|(0.75){\dir{>}} "b";"t"};
\endxy
\]
```

and get this diagram:

[image]

I have the following questions:

1. If I change `|(0.501)\hole` to `|(0.5)\hole`, the right part of arc disappears, why and how to fix it?
2. Making holes by `|(0.501)\hole` only works with `{\ar ... "b";"t"};`. If I use `"b";"t"**\crv{(10,0)&(0,10)&(-10,0)}?(0.501)*{\hole};` instead, the hole can not be seen in the diagram. Am I doing something wrong?
3. Can I use the calculating intersection function, by inserting something like `|!{"b";"t"}\hole`? I had the trouble in applying `!` to the curves.

Thank you!